# How to store file into inetpub\wwwroot instead of local machine folder on UWP application

Tags: iis, uwp, storage, wwwroot

I am currently developing a UWP application for my school project and one of the pages allows the user to take a picture of themselves. I created the feature by following this tutorial: [CameraStarterKit](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraStarterKit)

For now I am storing the pictures taken on my desktop's picture folder. But the requirement of my project is to store the pictures taken in a folder called "Photos" under **inetpub\wwwroot**.

I dont really understand what **wwwroot or IIS** is... hence, I have no idea how I should modify my codes and store them into the folder.

**Here are my codes for storing on my local desktop:**

```
private async Task TakePhotoAsync()
    {
        idleTimer.Stop();
        idleTimer.Start();

        var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

        //MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        //mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/camera-shutter-click-03.mp3"));
        //mediaPlayer.Play();

        Debug.WriteLine("Taking photo...");
        await _mediaCapture.CapturePhotoToStreamAsync(ImageEncodingProperties.CreateJpeg(), stream);




        try
        {
            var file = await _captureFolder.CreateFileAsync("NYPVisitPhoto.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
            Debug.WriteLine("Photo taken! Saving to " + file.Path);

            var photoOrientation = CameraRotationHelper.ConvertSimpleOrientationToPhotoOrientation(_rotationHelper.GetCameraCaptureOrientation());

            await ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(stream, file, photoOrientation);
            Debug.WriteLine("Photo saved!");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // File I/O errors are reported as exceptions
            Debug.WriteLine("Exception when taking a photo: " + ex.ToString());
        }



    }
```

**For the storing of the files:**

```
private static async Task ReencodeAndSavePhotoAsync(IRandomAccessStream stream, StorageFile file, PhotoOrientation photoOrientation)
    {
        using (var inputStream = stream)
        {
            var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(inputStream);

            using (var outputStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateForTranscodingAsync(outputStream, decoder);

                var properties = new BitmapPropertySet { { "System.Photo.Orientation", new BitmapTypedValue(photoOrientation, PropertyType.UInt16) } };

                await encoder.BitmapProperties.SetPropertiesAsync(properties);
                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You cannot do this with UWP, the app doesn’t have access to that folder. You can consider doing it with another component, like a script that automatically copies the taken picture from Pictures library to that folder.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the information... but may I know the reason why we cant do it with UWP? so that I write a report to my teacher and explain to them why I can do it. And also, I might like to try coping the taken picture from Pictures library to the folder, but how can I do it? script as in javascript? Thank you so much!:)

Comment: Or is there anyway I can have access to that folder on the app?

Comment: The list of folders a UWP app can access: [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions). You can try the open folder picker, which can also be found in the link.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an answer since there are tricky things about this requirement.

The first is the app [can only access a few folders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions), inetpub is not one of them.

Using brokered Windows runtime component (I would suggest using FullTrustProcessLauncher, which is much simpler to develop and deploy) can enable UWP apps access folders in the same way as the traditional desktop applications do.

While this works for an ordinary folder,  the inetpub folder, however, is different that it requires **Administrators Privileges** to write to, unless you turn UAC off.

The desktop component launched by the app does not have the adequate privileges to write to that folder, either.

So it think an alternative way would be setting up a virtual directory in IIS manager that maps to a folder in the public Pictures library, and the app saves picture to that folder.

From the website’s perspective, a virtual directory is the same as a real folder under inetpub, what differs is the access permissions.

Comment: Great approach! It's a great approach, I didn't know about FullTrustProcessLauncher, will read about it, Thanks!

Comment: @IpsitGaur Thanks! It is a new feature in UWP, add a desktop exe to the appx package, and then launch the exe from the app. All you need to do is declaring capabilities properly in appx manifest, this is much easier than brokered component, the short coming of it is you cannot get return execution results.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much for the suggestions! Just one question... will it be achievable if I choose to upload the files into the folder? I read abit about www.root and came across "upload" not very sure what it does... or it is similar to what I can looking for (which is unable to achieve)

Comment: @thalassophile if you mean upload to the IIS folder from within your app, then yes! Then you will need to not just implement the uwp app, but also an http endpoint that you can call to POST the data.

Comment: @kennyzx yup, can I upload into that "Photos" folder within that the application? Oh no what is http endpint... Im sorry.... very new to all these

Comment: @thalassophile I mean an ASP.NET application which can accepts data “POST” (in this case, the picture) from the app and save it to that folder. Like if you need to add a screenshot to your question, this website Stackoverflow.com needs to provide some API. If you have no experience in web programming, this is not a trivial task.

Answer (score 0):

**Kennyzx** is right here that you cannot access inetpub folder through your UWP application due to permissions.

But if your application fulfills following criteria then you can use **Brokered Windows Component**(a component within your app) to copy your file to any location in the system.

1. Your application is a LOB application
2. You are only targetting desktop devices(I assume this will be true because of your requirement)
3. You are using side-loading for your app installation and distribution.

If all three are Yes then use [Brokered Windows Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/winrt-components/brokered-windows-runtime-components-for-side-loaded-windows-store-apps) for UWP, it's not a small thing that can be showed here on SO using an example. So give worth a try reading and implementing it.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the suggestions! Unfortunately, my application doesnt fulfills the criteria listed...